# How can i add sdcard images to coverflow?

Tags: android, image, drawable, android-sdcard, coverflow

[image]
Here is my coverflow with drawables :(
This is my Image Adapter Code

```
    /** The Constant IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS. */
private static final List<Integer> IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS = new ArrayList<Integer>(DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE);

/** The Constant DEFAULT_RESOURCE_LIST. */
private static final int[] DEFAULT_RESOURCE_LIST = {
    R.drawable.promo_blue_bg_medium,
    R.drawable.promo_green_bg_medium,
    R.drawable.flow,
    R.drawable.promo_yellow_bg_medium,
    R.drawable.promo_black_bg_medium ,

};

/** The bitmap map. */
private final Map<Integer, WeakReference<Bitmap>> bitmapMap = new HashMap<Integer, WeakReference<Bitmap>>();

private final Context context;

/**
 * Creates the adapter with default set of resource images.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            context
 */
public ResourceImageAdapter(final Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    setResources(DEFAULT_RESOURCE_LIST);
}

/**
 * Replaces resources with those specified.
 * 
 * @param resourceIds
 *            array of ids of resources.
 */
public final synchronized void setResources(final int[] resourceIds) {



       String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
         .getExternalStorageDirectory()
         .getAbsolutePath();

       String targetPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + "/CamWay/";



       File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);


    IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.clear();
    for (final int resourceId : resourceIds) {
        IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.add(resourceId);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
 */
@Override
public synchronized int getCount() {
    return IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.size();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see pl.polidea.coverflow.AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter#createBitmap(int)
 */
@Override
protected Bitmap createBitmap(final int position) {
    Log.v(TAG, "creating item " + position);
    final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.get(position)))
            .getBitmap();
    bitmapMap.put(position, new WeakReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

You see,5 drawable listed above.I wanna load 5 last added images from folder.How can i add sdcard images to that code.

I'm trying to showing 5 last taken photos with coverflow.
I hope somebody can help me.

EDIT(last code):

```
    public class ResourceImageAdapter extends AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter {

    //Dosya alımı başlangıç
     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private Context mContext;
            ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

            public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
             mContext = c; 
            }

            void add(String path){
             itemList.add(path); 
            }

         @Override
         public int getCount() {
          return itemList.size();
         }

         @Override
         public Object getItem(int position) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return itemList.get(position);
         }

         @Override
         public long getItemId(int position) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return 0;
         }

         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          ImageView imageView;
                if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                } else {
                    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                }

                Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                return imageView;
         }

         public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

          Bitmap bm = null;
          // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
          final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
          options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
          BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

          // Calculate inSampleSize
          options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

          // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
          options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
          bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options); 

          return bm;   
         }

         public int calculateInSampleSize(

          BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
          // Raw height and width of image
          final int height = options.outHeight;
          final int width = options.outWidth;
          int inSampleSize = 1;

          if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
           if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);    
           } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);    
           }   
          }

          return inSampleSize;    
         }

        }

           ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

           //Burası Dosya alımı bitimi
    /** The Constant TAG. */
    private static final String TAG = ResourceImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    /** The Constant DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE. */
    private static final int DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE = 20;

    /** The Constant IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS. */
    private static final List<Integer> IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS = new ArrayList<Integer>(DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE);

    /** The Constant DEFAULT_RESOURCE_LIST. */
    private static final int[] DEFAULT_RESOURCE_LIST = {
        R.drawable.promo_blue_bg_medium,
        R.drawable.promo_green_bg_medium,
        R.drawable.flow,
        R.drawable.promo_yellow_bg_medium,
        R.drawable.promo_black_bg_medium ,

    };
    private String[] mFileStrings;
    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();

   public void getFromSdcard()
   {
       File file=  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() ,"CamWay");

           if (file.isDirectory())
           {
               File[] listFile = file.listFiles();//get list of filess
               mFileStrings = new String[listFile.length];

               for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
               {
                   mFileStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                   f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());//add path of files to array list
                   System.out.println("...................................."+mFileStrings[i]);
               }
           }
   }

    /** The bitmap map. */
    private final Map<Integer, WeakReference<Bitmap>> bitmapMap = new HashMap<Integer, WeakReference<Bitmap>>();

    private final Context context;

    /**
     * Creates the adapter with default set of resource images.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            context
     */
    public ResourceImageAdapter(final Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        setResources(DEFAULT_RESOURCE_LIST);
    }

    /**
     * Replaces resources with those specified.
     * 
     * @param resourceIds
     *            array of ids of resources.
     */
    public final synchronized void setResources(final int[] resourceIds) {



           String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
             .getExternalStorageDirectory()
             .getAbsolutePath();

           String targetPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + "/CamWay/";



           File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);


        IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.clear();
        for (final int resourceId : resourceIds) {
            IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.add(resourceId);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized int getCount() {
        return IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.size();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see pl.polidea.coverflow.AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter#createBitmap(int)
     */
    @Override
    protected Bitmap createBitmap(final int position) {
        Log.v(TAG, "creating item " + position);
        final Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));

        bitmapMap.put(position, new WeakReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 :

it starts and then shows 3 items from beginning .when i try look 4+ item ,it stops.
this is code -- `getFromSdcard() ; int size= f.size()-5; //get the size of arraylist then decrease it by 5 //then loop from that point to your arraylist size //to get the last 5 items in the list for(int j=size;j<f.size();j++) { System.out.println("Position = "+j); System.out.println("Path of files"+f.get(j)); } final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position)); bitmapMap.put(position, new WeakReference<Bitmap>(bitmap)); return bitmap;`

```
04-06 21:41:05.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11217): at     com.project.smyrna.camway.ResourceImageAdapter.createBitmap(ResourceImageAdapter‌​.java:152)
```

--line is `final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String[] mFileStrings;
 ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();

public void getFromSdcard()
{
    File file=  new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Your Sdcard");

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            listFile = file.listFiles();//get list of files
            for (int i = listFile.length-5; i < listFile.length; i++)
            {
                    //get the length decrease it 5 . loop to last 
                mFileStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());//add path of files to array list
                System.out.println("...................................."+mFileStrings[i]);
            }
        }
}
```

You can get the path of files under a folder in your sdcard. But make sure the sdcard folder does not have other file formats. Then pass the arraylist to your adapter to display the same in coverflow

To filter files that are .png you can use the below

```
 File dir= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Then call

```
walkdir(dir);

ArrayList<String> filepath= new ArrayList<String>();//contains list of all files ending with 

public void walkdir(File dir) {
String Patternpng = ".png";

File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

if (listFile != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
    walkdir(listFile[i]);
} else {
  if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(Patternpng)){
      //Do what ever u want
      filepath.add( listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }
   }
  }  
 }    
 }
```

From the comment made i assume you need to display last 5 items from your sdcard folder

```
         int  size= f.size()-5; 
         //get the size of arraylist then decrease it by 5
         //then loop from that point to your arraylist size 
         //to get the last 5 items in the list
         for(int j=size;j<f.size();j++)
         {
             System.out.println("Position = "+j);
             System.out.println("Path of files"+f.get(j));  
         }
```

Your adapter

```
 public class MyAdapter extends AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter {


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return f.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      //inflate layout
          //do something
          //use the edit 2 to get last 5 items in the arraylist.
          ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.ivv);
          Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
          image.setImageBitmap(b);     
    }

  }
```

UPDATE:

1. Add only last 5 file paths to your arraylist f in getFromSdcard()
2. Your listview item count is f.size()
3. To get the paths  you can use f.get(position) in getview().

In getFromSdcard()

```
        for (int i = listFile.length-5; i < listFile.length; i++)
         // add only last 5 file paths from your folder
```

In your adapter

```
@Override
 public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return f.size();
}
```

In getView

```
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.ivv);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
        image.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: thank you so much .i understand but i couldn't implement that.        final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(f.get(position)))--it says f should be int .i'm a bit confused

Comment: Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position)); check the edit

Comment: 04-06 20:29:24.075: E/AndroidRuntime(28472): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0
--        final Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));----i've get this exception.i think something wrong .what size?!?? i'm trying understand---

Comment: old code-------- @Override
    protected Bitmap createBitmap(final int position) {
        Log.v(TAG, "creating item " + position);
        final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(IMAGE_RESOURCE_IDS.get(position)))
                .getBitmap();
        bitmapMap.put(position, new WeakReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
        return bitmap;
    }

Comment: new code -----  @Override
    protected Bitmap createBitmap(final int position) {
        Log.v(TAG, "creating item " + position);
        final Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
              
        bitmapMap.put(position, new WeakReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
        return bitmap;
    }

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: thanks so much again .. i've edited .you can see last code above :)

Comment: Have you called getFromSdcard() method somewhere in your code? Because from the log you posted the size seems to be zero. You need to call the method getFromSdcard(). you have defined the method but where do you call the method??

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH :D :D YOU SOLVED MY PROBLEM.I'M WORKİNG ON IT ABOUT 8 HOURS :D THANKS SO MUCH :)) and if you want to know what i'm actually doing you can install "camway" app from play store.it is my app :D :) Thanks again dude :D

Comment: but one thing i want ask .where did you implement (last 5 items) ? :)) edit : and actually you did first 5 items.how can i get last 5 items??

Comment: Ok,i'm trying again(sorry for my english :) )..i didn't understand where you define 5 items.Because,coverflow gets 5 items from the beginning.and another question is : how can i get last 5 items? I hope you understand. :)

Comment: i found sorry :D code gets old drawables count.i won't change :P :D but,still i couldn't find how can i get last 5 items ? :)

Comment: how can i get (last) 5 items to coverflow ?

Comment: get last 5 items from where? you need to take care of listview item count. f.size(); this is the listview item count. You want to display only last 5 items in the list.

Comment: yes i want only last 5 items...but coverflow gets 5 items from beginning not last...

Comment: check edit 1 and edit 3. your list of path ie arraylist f should containd last 5 paths of files from your folder. Next using the path display the same in coverflow. i assume this what your looking for. If you still can't make a way through ask a new question.

Comment: you keep the listview iten count f.size() since in getFromSdcard()  you are adding only the last 5 path to the arraylist.

Comment: it starts and then shows 3 items from beginning .when i try look 4+ item ,it stops.---

Comment: this is code -- 
        getFromSdcard() ;
        int  size= f.size()-5; 
        //get the size of arraylist then decrease it by 5
        //then loop from that point to your arraylist size 
        //to get the last 5 items in the list
        for(int j=size;j<f.size();j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Position = "+j);
            System.out.println("Path of files"+f.get(j));  
        }
        final Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
              
        bitmapMap.put(position, new WeakReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
        
        return bitmap;

Comment: error is 04-06 21:41:05.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11217):  at com.project.smyrna.camway.ResourceImageAdapter.createBitmap(ResourceImageAdapter.java:152)
--line is         final Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));

Comment: and now working with bugs ...it shows 5 last but..3 images are showing.. 4th 5th ones blank and when i slide, camway app stops

Comment: The above answer works perfectlyif you implement it correctly. I you still find problem as a new  question with clear details in SO. New Question meaning not updating the old one.

Comment: i did some optimizations and it works :D thank you so much dude :D THANK YOU  :D AND SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH AGAIN :) you're best helper in this website :D you're very good at android programming.