# How create Custom gallery by reading all images stored in android internal storage

Tags: android, gallery, image-gallery, android-gallery

I am developing an android app in which i am saving images in a specified folder after some editing.Now i want to show all these stored images in my activity. I m able to show a particular image by specifying a particular name.But i want to show all images together.. Thank in advance.
 I m using Following code to show single image......

```
 File myDir=new File("/sdcard/MyCollection");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    try {
        File f=new File(myDir, "My Image name.jpg");   
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        img.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557650/how-to-display-images-saved-in-sdcard-folder-in-android

Comment: Thanks a lot ..........you have solve my big problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i follow your question, than you can retrieve the list of file with `.jpg` extension run a loop on list and show in imageview.

```
    File root = new File("/sdcard/MyCollection");
    final String files[] = root.list(imageFilter);
    FilenameFilter imageFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        File f;
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        if(name.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                return true;
            }
            f = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+name);

            return f.isDirectory();
        }
    };
```

`files` will return an array of files.You can loop on it.

Comment: if it works and you think it useful...you can accept it as a answer.

Comment: Further, You can use `gridView` to show a Matrix of image thumbnails just like a gallery

Comment: that is the way of dealing to show the images... that can be achieved with simple listview also... that depends on requirement of app...

Comment: i think that this is better :  if(name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) {
                    return true;
                }