# Android swipe screen with circle indication

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am new to android and I need some basic explanation on how to create a tutorial with circle indicator as shown on image below
[image]

I have used ViewPager but it moves whole screen together with my image of the circles which does not look good. I was reading about JakeWhatron's viewPageIndicator but I after core solution for my problem.

Comment: so what do you want to move? just the text? This is an example from the app im currently working on - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8CNLWhHBdgsdEhfSVpvMjNUUGM/view?usp=docslist_api I used Jake Whatrons library btw :) do you want something similar to that?

Comment: Yes, I want to move just the text. BTW your login screen looks great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can get circle indicator with text using Jake Whatron's library

add this to build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
```

put your desired image as background of your main layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/hello_layour"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background_image"  // add your background image here
    tools:context=".HelloActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

add this where you want the indicator and the text

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager // the actual text you want will be shows here
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator // this is the circular indicator 
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a new class add the following data (this is the adapter for the viewpager):

```
package com.your.packagename;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class WelcomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    private Context context;
    private String[] title;
    private String[] description;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public WelcomePagerAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] description) {
        this.context = context;
        this.title= title;
        this.description= description;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return title.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView titleView;
        TextView descriptionView;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // layout inflator
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_pager, container,
            false);

        // title text holder
        titleView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.welcome_title);
        titleView.setText(title[position]);

        // description text holder
        descriptionView= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.welcome_description);
        descriptionView.setText(description[position]);

        // add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;

    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }
}
```

create an xml file for the layout of the viewpager item..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/welcome_title"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_title"
        android:id="@+id/welcome_description"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="15sp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now finally just add this to the onCreate() section of your tutorial activity:

```
    // pager titles
    String[] titles = new String[]{"Random Title One", "Random Title Two",
            "Random Title Three", "Random Title Four"};

    // pager descriptions
    String[] descriptions= new String[]{"random small description example", "random small description example",
            "random small description example", "random small description example"};

    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    PagerAdapter adapter = new WelcomePagerAdapter(this, titles, descriptions);

    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // ViewPager Indicator
    CirclePageIndicator mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: Hi edwinj! Thanks for the detailed information. I do not understand android in such matter to figure out everything from your advice. Where do I exactly put the last bit in the onCreate section? At the moment I have: `WelcomePagerAdapter class`, `welcomepageradapter_layout.xml` and `fragment_a.xml` Do I need more then this? Thank you for your help and support

Comment: @Lenny you can put it anywhere in the onCreateView section of your fragment. (its just onCreate if you are using an activity btw) :)

Comment: thank you! And if I'd would like to have moving images as in your video where should I put them?

Comment: @edwinj. How can I download and import this library into android studio?

Comment: @edwinj. I download this arr file and import it to android studio- but it shows me: `Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not find library.aar (com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/viewpagerindicator/library/2.4.1/library-2.4.1.aar`. What should i do? please help!!!

Comment: @MinaDahesh: use `compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'`

Comment: @edwinj. Is it possible to change the circle's color? How? I want to make it black.

Comment: I find out  this link, that is very simple and use full. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40047719/3671748

Comment: Instead of that just try to add dependency of " compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar' . And it will work

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewPager with CirclePageAdapter.

```
<com.movie.bms.utils.customcomponents.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

    <com.movie.bms.utils.customcomponents.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/circle_page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
```

Then in your activity, attach it with your viewPager.

```
circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

Check this answer for better explanation.

[Viewpager indicator with images selected from gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424736/viewpager-indicator-with-images-selected-from-gallery/35425354#35425354)